# PayPal React Integration not creating transaction

Tags: reactjs, paypal, checkout

I'm trying to integrate with PayPal checkout using the react library (@paypal/react-paypal-js), the response of the payment is successful, but when I use the live client id it doesn't bill from my credit card.

```
import { api } from "../services/api";
import { PayPalButtons, PayPalScriptProvider } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";


export default function Pagamento() {

  function createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            value: "2.00",
          },
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  function onApprove(data, actions) {
    console.log(data);
    const paymentID = data.paymentID;
    const orderID = data.orderID;
    const payerID = data.payerID;

    api
      .get("update_pacientes", {
        params: {
          username: username,
          column: "status",
          paymentID: paymentID,
          orderID: orderID,
          payerID: payerID,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        // , location.reload();
      });
  }


  return (
    <div id="pagamento_wrapper">
      
        <PayPalScriptProvider
          options={{
            "client-id": OMMITED FOR SECURITY REASONS
             ,
            currency: "BRL",
          }}
        >
          <PayPalButtons
            style={{ color: "blue", shape: "pill", label: "pay", height: 40 }}
            createOrder={(data, actions) => createOrder(data, actions)}
            onApprove={(data, actions) => onApprove(data, actions)}
          />
        </PayPalScriptProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `onApprove` function is not capturing the order after the payer approves it, so there is no PayPal transaction created.

Since from inside `createOrder` you used `actions.order.create` to create on the client side, you should also capture on the client side via `actions.order.capture` (from inside `onApprove`)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Hi, I added the following line on my onApprove function and it worked:
return actions.order.capture();
Thank you so much!